# Cast single character so it can be used where a char * is needed

Tags: c, casting

How to correctly cast SEPARATOR in the following code while calling the send_data function?

***foo.h***

```
#define SEPARATOR 0xFF

void send_data(unsigned char * data, int dataSize);
```

***foo.c***

```
void welcome(){
   // I want to call it in a one line
   send_data(SEPARATOR ,1);
}
```

*Btw, of course I can define the SEPARATOR as a const char. But I just wonder about if there is any way to use it like that.*

Comment: Do you want to set the address as 0xFF to send_data or the value as 0xFF. In the code above you are setting the address as 0xFF, in which case there should be some meaningful data at that address.

Comment: "Cast" means using the same data as if it was a different type. You want to get a pointer to some value - it isn't called "cast".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old-school way would be to work around it, if you don't want to change it:

```
void welcome(void)
{
  unsigned char data = SEPARATOR;
  send_data(&data, 1);
}
```

But you should also be able to use a C99 compound literal:

```
send_data((unsigned char[1]) { SEPARATOR }, 1);
```

Comment: send_data((unsigned char[1]) { SEPARATOR }, 1); >> ugly but what I've asked for. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Compound literals (C99 or later) may be useful.

```
void welcome(){
   // I want to call it in a one line
   send_data((unsigned char[]){SEPARATOR} ,1);
}
```

Add terminating null-character if it is required.

```
void welcome(){
   // I want to call it in a one line
   send_data((unsigned char[]){SEPARATOR, 0} ,1);
}
```

Comment: The second argument to `send_data()` is the length, so 0-termination (with unchanged length of `1`) makes little sense.

Comment: @unwind It is not obvious if the function works with strings or with raw data. Without clarification of what the function does, this code is safer than your version. Suppose for example that the function passes on both parameters to `strncpy` or similar.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree. Any code dealing with `unsigned char` explicitly is trying to signal "I want raw bytes", in my world (since the signedness of `char` is implementation-specific), and having an explicit length field makes that even more clear. Doing it @MikeCAT's way is ambiguous, doing work to create a buffer that is longer than you then say to the function getting that buffer is a code smell, in my opinion.

Comment: @unwind There's coding standards that ban the use of `char` entirely, for that very reason. Meaning you'd have to work with `unsigned char` for strings, which does make sense since symbol tables are unlikely to have negative indices. The presence of the `0xFF` constant does suggest that this isn't a string though... would be good if the OP could clarify this.